# Mocking config with spring boot isn't picking up property files

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, spring-integration

I am trying to write a IntegrationFlow test. It goes something like this:

> JMS(in) -> (find previous versions in db) -> reduce(in,1...n) -> (to db) -> JMS(out)

So, no suprise: I want to mock the DB calls; they are Dao beans. But, I also want it to pickup other beans through component scan; I will selectively scan all packages except dao.

- Create a test config and mock the Daos. No problem
- Follow spring boot instructions for testing to get Component scanned beans. No problem

I just want to verify the sequence of steps and the resultant output as the outbound JMS queue would see it. Can someone just help me fill in the blanks?

This **CANT** be tough! The use of mocks seems to be problematic because plenty of essential fields are final. I am reading everywhere about this and just not coming up with a clear path. I inherited this code BTW

My error:

> org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:retry-context.xml")
public class LifecycleConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MessageProducerSupport inbound;

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler outbound;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("reducer")
    private GenericTransformer<Collection<ExtendedClaim>,ExtendedClaim> reducer;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("claimIdToPojo")
    private GenericTransformer<String,ClaimDomain> toPojo;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("findPreviousVersion")
    private GenericTransformer<ExtendedClaim,Collection<ExtendedClaim>> previousVersions;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saveToDb")
    private GenericHandler<ExtendedClaim> toDb;

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel getChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public StandardIntegrationFlow processClaim() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(inbound).
                channel(getChannel()).
                transform(previousVersions).
                transform(reducer).
                handle(ExtendedClaim.class,toDb).
                transform(toPojo).
                handle(outbound).get();
    }
}
```

Test Config

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends AbstractClsTest {


    @Bean(name = "claimIdToPojo")
    public ClaimIdToPojo getClaimIdToPojo() {
        return spy(new ClaimIdToPojo());
    }

    @Bean
    public ClaimToId getClaimToIdPojo() {
        return spy(new ClaimToId());
    }

    @Bean(name = "findPreviousVersion")
    public FindPreviousVersion getFindPreviousVersion() {
        return spy(new FindPreviousVersion());
    }

    @Bean(name = "reducer")
    public Reducer getReducer() {
        return spy(new Reducer());
    }

    @Bean(name = "saveToDb")
    public SaveToDb getSaveToDb() {
        return spy(new SaveToDb());
    }

    @Bean
    public  MessageProducerSupport getInbound() {
        MessageProducerSupport mock = mock(MessageProducerSupport.class);
//        when(mock.isRunning()).thenReturn(true);
        return mock;
    }

    @Bean
    public PaymentDAO getPaymentDao() {
        return mock(PaymentDAO.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClaimDAO getClaimDao() {
        return mock(ClaimDAO.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler getOutbound() {
        return new CaptureHandler<ExtendedClaim>();
    }

}
```

Actual test won't load

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, LifecycleConfig.class})
public class ClaimLifecycleApplicationTest extends AbstractClsTest {


    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler outbound;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("reducer")
    private GenericTransformer<Collection<ExtendedClaim>,ExtendedClaim> reducer;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("claimIdToPojo")
    private GenericTransformer<String,ClaimDomain> toPojo;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("findPreviousVersion")
    private GenericTransformer<ExtendedClaim,Collection<ExtendedClaim>> previousVersions;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("saveToDb")
    private GenericHandler<ExtendedClaim> toDb;

    @Autowired
    private DirectChannel defaultChannel;

    @Test
    public void testFlow() throws Exception {

        ExtendedClaim claim = getClaim();
        Message<ExtendedClaim> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(claim).build();
        List<ExtendedClaim> previousClaims = Arrays.asList(claim);

        defaultChannel.send(message);
        verify(previousVersions).transform(claim);
        verify(reducer).transform(previousClaims);
        verify(toDb).handle(claim, anyMap());
        verify(toPojo).transform(claim.getSubmitterClaimId());
        verify(outbound);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of domain-specific object, so I can't test it to reproduce or find some other issue with your code.

But I see that you don't use an `@EnableIntegration` on your `@Configuration`s classes.

Comment: Ok, let me look into that. And, as for the domain stuff: Yeah, you're right. I am at my witts end